# How to get full path name of Serilog log file?

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I am prototyping using Serilog in a .NET 7 console app. For a number of existing console apps, we copy, email, or otherwise process log/results files.  So, I'd like to get the fully qualified filename of the log file that Serilog has written to.  Any links to information about how to do that?  I have looked at the Serilog website, but it's a bit sparse, IMHO.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .MinimumLevel.Debug()
           .WriteTo.Console()
           .WriteTo.File("MyConsoleApp.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
           .CreateLogger();
```